# Is there any possible way to reduce the spaces between labels and text fields in simpleform

Tags: sapui5

i have created a simple form with input and text fields which is responsive :

```
 <f:SimpleForm id="customercell" 
               editable="true"
               layout="ResponsiveGridLayout"
               columnsL="1"
               columnsM="1">
    <f:content>
        <Label text="Customer Name">
        <layoutData>
        <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S2"/>
        </layoutData>
        </Label>
        <Text class="custom" text="{customerData>/CustomerValue}">
        <layoutData>
        <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S2"/>
        </layoutData>
        </Text>
        <Label text="Customer Number">
        <layoutData>
        <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S2"/>
        </layoutData>
        </Label>
        <Text text="{customerData>/CustomerNumber}">
        <layoutData>
        <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S2"/>
        </layoutData>
        </Text>
        <Label text="Email">
        <layoutData>
        <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S2"/>
        </layoutData>
        </Label>
        <Text text="{EmailData>/Email}">
        <layoutData>
        <l:GridData span="L2 M2 S2"/>
        </layoutData>
        </Text>
</f:content>
</f:SimpleForm>
```

I am getting much space between input and text area which doesn't looks nice with much space is it possible to remove spaces between input and text area can anyone help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Change  `labelSpanXL`, `labelSpanL`,  `labelSpanM`, `labelSpanS` values to adjust the space between them.

Comment: I have adjusted but there is no change do we need to add any css

Comment: CSS is not required as per my understanding so far. Kindly share the screenshots as well for better understanding.

Comment: https://ibb.co/64BWBJ4 this is my output and i am trying to remove the space between input and text fields